# How should I delete branch from adjacency list in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, hierarchy

Given a basic acyclic adjacency list like this:

What is the most effective way to handle deletions of branches?

My current approach uses a recursive CTE to find all descendant nodes and their depths (n). Then I iterate (ugh) over those depths in reverse and issue n deletes.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TreeNode](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentNodeId] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TreeNode] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TreeNode]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_TreeNode_TreeNode] FOREIGN KEY([ParentNodeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TreeNode] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TreeNode]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_TreeNode_Id_ParentNodeId] CHECK  (([Id]<>[ParentNodeId]))
GO
```

`ON DELETE CASCADE` won't work here because it isn't allowed in self-referencing FKs

Comment: I would define the FK constraint as `on delete cascade` and then simply delete the starting node.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That approach isn't very effective for me because I have additional logic I need to do given the IDs of the deleted nodes.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually, I couldn't even if I wanted to. `ON DELETE CASCADE` is not allowed on adjacency lists like this that could by cyclic.

Answer (score 3):

No need for a procedure, just combine the CTE with a `DELETE`

```
with doomed as (
  select id, ParentNodeId
  from treenode
  where id = ... --<< start node of the branch to be deleted
  union all
  select c.id, c.ParentNodeId
  from treenode c
    join doomed p on c.parentnodeid = p.id
)
delete from treenode 
where id in (select id from doomed);
```

Comment: That's really neat

Comment: Nice. And I think you don't even need the `ParentNodeId` column in the cte in the actual delete statement. (it can of course be useful if you want to select first the results to check what will be deleted ;)

Comment: @ypercube: yes, that's how it got in there ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about trying using a little recursion. No need to keep track of the depth of the node with some clunky code, just let the stack do that for you with a clean and simple procedure.

First, define your procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_DEL_NODES @inNode INT 
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @delNode INT 

 --If there exists a child who's parent is being deleted, do a recursive call
 WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 ID FROM [dbo].[TreeNode] where ParentNodeId = @inNode)
 BEGIN
   -- get the next child node and delete it via recursive call
   SELECT TOP(1) @delNode = ID FROM [dbo].[TreeNode] where ParentNodeId = @inNode
   exec USP_DEL_NODES @delNode -- Recursive call with the child node
 END

 --Finally, delete the node who's ID was passed as input
 DELETE FROM [dbo].[TreeNode] WHERE id = @inNode

END
```

Then, call it with the id of the node you wish to delete, along with it's children ;

```
exec USP_DEL_NODES 2 --If you want to delete node number 2 and it's children
```

Another way to go would be to use the parentNodeId as a key for the deletion, that probably yields better results in terms of number of iterations

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_DEL_NODES2 @inNode INT 
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @delNode INT 

 --If there exists a grandchild, do a recursive call
 WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[TreeNode] where ParentNodeId IN (SELECT ID FROM [dbo].[TreeNode] where ParentNodeId = @inNode))
 BEGIN
   -- get the next child node and delete it via recursive call
   SELECT TOP(1) @delNode = ID FROM [dbo].[TreeNode] where ParentNodeId IN (SELECT ID FROM [dbo].[TreeNode] where ParentNodeId = @inNode)
   exec USP_DEL_NODES2 @delNode -- Recursive call with the child node
 END

 --Finally, delete the node who's ID was passed as input, and it's children
 DELETE FROM [dbo].[TreeNode] WHERE ParentNodeId = @inNode OR id = @inNode

END
```

Comment: My current implementation runs L deletes where L is the number of levels. Your implementation runs N deletes, where N is the number of nodes.

Comment: Just added another version of the proc, it goes by the parentNodeId. Should only iterate over the number of levels.

Comment: I wonder if this can be accomplished in a recursive CTE rather than recursive sproc calls?